# Converting strings to buffers and back again

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, clr

I have a SQL Server UDF calling a CLR DLL (C#.Net) calling an unmanaged C/C++ DLL.  As a test I am just trying to XOR a SQL VARCHAR or NVARCHAR and pass it back again. I am trying to do it without any CASTs or CONVERTS in the SQL code that calls the UDF.  Unfortunately, calling the UDF (bottom) results in the literal string `"System.Byte[]"` rather than the XOR'd string.

I tried to strip down / simplify this as much as possible. I have included the C/C++, C#, and TSQL portions of the test project.

Any tips on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
/* _MY_XOR.C */
__declspec(dllexport) 
void _my_xor(UCHAR *dataIn, int dataLength)
{
    while (dataLength-- > 0)
        *dataIn++ ^= 0xFF;
}

/* MY_XOR.CS */
[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
static extern void _my_xor(byte[] dataIn, int dataLength);
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction] 
[return: SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)]
public static SqlString MY_XOR([SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)]SqlString dataIn)
{
    if (dataIn.IsNull)
        return null;
    byte[] bytesIn = dataIn.GetNonUnicodeBytes();
    _my_xor(bytesIn, bytesIn.Length);
        SqlString dataOut = new SqlString(bytesIn.ToString());
    return dataOut;
}

/* MY_XOR.SQL */
CREATE FUNCTION MY_XOR(@data nvarchar(MAX)) RETURNS nvarchar(MAX) 
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER AS EXTERNAL NAME MYPCLR.UserDefinedFunctions.MY_XOR;

/* Sample usage */
DECLARE @hello nvarchar(32), @result nvarchar(32);
set @hello = N'Hello World';
set @result = dbo.MY_XOR(@hello);
select @hello 'hello', @result 'result';
```

Result: @result contains literal string "System.Byte[]" instead of XOR'd "Hello World".

PS - I know I can do the XOR in C#, but this is for problem solving, not specifically for XORing.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SqlString` constructor that accepts a `byte[]` directly, such as [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xss3f8et%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public SqlString(
    int lcid,
    SqlCompareOptions compareOptions,
    byte[] data
)
```

Rather than the one that accepts a string here:

```
SqlString dataOut = new SqlString(bytesIn.ToString());
```

It's that call to `ToString()` on the `byte[]` that's resulting in the output of `System.Byte[]`.

So, I think something like this would work:

```
SqlString dataOut = new SqlString(dataIn.LCID, dataIn.SqlCompareOptions,bytesIn);
```